# SQL Synapse Compare data between Column(multiple values) and Column(multiple values)

Tags: sql-server, azure-synapse

I need to compare 2 columns from 2 tables.

table a:

```
ID|TEL
----------------
A1|1111,2222,3333
```

TABLE B:

```
ID|TEL
----------------
A1|2222,4444
```

Result should update in TABLE A

```
A1|1111,2222,3333,4444
```

As I know, maybe I should use select value from string_split (B.Tel,'|') to split it. However, I don't know how to loop to compare between A and B.

Please help.

Here is what I've tried but it's not working.

```
    with split_tel as
       (select id, 
       Value tel
from B
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(tel, ','))
,pre as (select sp.id
        ,sp.tel as split
        ,A.tel as target
from split_tel sp 
inner join A
on sp.id = A.id)

select id,split,target
from pre
where split like '%' + target + '%' ;
```

Comment: I have already edited what I've tried above, but is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should not really be storing your data like this, particularly if you are having to conduct set-based operations on it.  However there is a simple solution using `STRING_SPLIT` and `STRING_AGG` if you are always effectively adding numbers, not taking away:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmpA') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmpA
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmpB') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmpB

CREATE TABLE #tmpA ( 
    id      VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    tel     VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL

);

CREATE TABLE #tmpB ( 
    id      VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    tel     VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL

);

--INSERT INTO #tmpA VALUES ( 'A1', '1111,2222,3333' );
--INSERT INTO #tmpB VALUES ( 'A1', '2222,4444' );

INSERT INTO #tmpA 
SELECT 'A1', '1111,2222,3333'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'B1', '2222'

INSERT INTO #tmpB 
SELECT 'A1', '2222,4444'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'B1', '3333'


SELECT id, STRING_AGG( value, ',' ) tel
FROM
    (
    SELECT a.id, x.value
    FROM #tmpA a
        CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT( a.tel, ',' ) x
    UNION
    SELECT b.id, x.value
    FROM #tmpB b
        CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT( b.tel, ',' ) x
    ) y
GROUP BY id;
```

Comment: Thanks, I've followed your advice and modified some part to fit my job. It's work.